# C++ Multi-threading with multiple machines

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix

Well my problem is the following. I have a piece of code that runs on several virtual machines, and each virtual machine has N interfaces(a thread per each). The problem itself is receiving a message on one interface and redirect it through another interface in the fastest possible manner.

What I'm doing is, when I receive a message on one interface(Unicast), calculate which interface I want to redirect it through, save all the information about the message(Datagram, and all the extra info I want) with a function I made. Then on the next iteration, the program checks if there are new messages to redirect and if it is the correct interface reading it. And so on... But this makes the program exchange information very slowly...

Is there any mechanism that can speed things up?

Comment: Unless you are working on a "close coupled" cluster, you don't mean multithreading here, you mean "multiprocessing" or perhaps "interprocess IO".

Comment: This is impossibly vague and open-ended. Can you post some sample code to show what you're currently doing, what performance figures you get and how you measured, etc. ?

Comment: @dmckee may be... I'm new to this, and that is what I was briefed...

Comment: @Useless I'm sorry, I know how it sounds, but I can't give code details or anything more specific due to a non disclosure agreement...

Comment: I was being a little pedantic, but the point is that "threads" have a relatively easy time communicating and synchronizing while separate processes are less likely to accidentally step on each other toes at the cost of more difficult communication and synchronization. SO people usually make a distinction between "multithreading" and "multiprocessing"; though it may be passing out of style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somebody has already invented this particular wheel - it's called MPI

Take a look at either [openMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) or [MPICH](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! I will check it out and see if I can fill all the requirements with that!!! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use queuing? As the messages come in, put them on a queue and notify each processing module to pick them up from the queue.
For example:

- MSG comes in
- Module 1 puts it on queue
- Module 2,3 get notified
- Module 2 picks it up from queue and saved it in the database
- In parallel, Module 3 picks it up from queue and processes it

The key is "in parallel". Since these modules are different threads, while Module 2 is saving to the db, Module 3 can massage your message.

You could use JMS or MQ or make your own queue.

Comment: Thanks for the information!!! I'll give a go on MPI, and if I can't manage everything, I'll try to adopt the Queuing mechanism

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do parallel computing across multiple "machines" (even if virtual).  You may want to look at existing protocols, such as [MPI - Message Passing Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) to handle this domain, as they have quite a few features that help in this type of scenario

Comment: Thanks for the information!!! I'll see if I can manage everything with MPI then!!!